# C#: use reflection to obtain reference to instance's member in constructor

Tags: c#, reflection

Given a class

```
public class MyClass
{
    public SomeObject myObject;
    public AnotherObject myOtherObject;
    // many more members

    public MyClass()
    {
        string name = getMemberNameAndValue();
        // name == "myObject" or "myOtherObject"

        // now obtain reference to _this_ instance's
        // member given by `name` so I can set its member's value.
    }
}
```

I don't simply want to obtain a new object that is the same type as that given by `name`, I want to get an actual reference to the member of the instance being created so I can set its own member's value.

**EDIT:**  I changed the name of the `get` function.  That is, this (server call) function not only retrieves the name of the member to be set, but also the value to set it to.  Which member (i.e. `myObject` or `myOtherObject`) is to be set is not fixed, and one may not be set at all.

**EDIT2:** The reason I intend(ed) to use reflection is that the list of member objects will be large and I wanted to avoid using many `if` statements or even a long `switch` (as recommended in the comments below).

Comment: What have you tried to do so far to set a field using reflection, and what problems have you had with your attempted solutions?

Comment: I'm rather confused by what you're trying to accomplish here.  Why do you need to use reflection for this?  Why can't you just use the actual instance to set its value?  Reflection is only necessary when you don't know what something might be.. but you do know that here.

Comment: the `getObjectName` method not only returns the value of `myObject` xor `myOtherObject`, but also which one is to be set.  Which means, I need to obtain member that is to be set (after the function call), and then set it.

Comment: @jayflo Quick style recommendation; that's not generally a good idea in a constructor. It sounds like a pretty poor design to me; that you would be conditionally initializing variables like that. Regardless; a simple `if` statement off a `bool` return value would seem to suffice here.

Comment: In the example, there are only two member objects.  In actuality, the number of many objects will be larger and I thought a large chain of `if` statements or a `switch` to conditionally set the value of these member objects would get out of hand.

Comment: @jayflo So you are trusting a *server* to give you correct reflection data. Thats a pretty big stretch to me. Also, I would *never* do IO in a constructor. Move it off to an `Init` thread or something. Just a few pieces of advice. Hopefully my answer showed you how to accomplish it; whether you should be doing it or not.

Comment: The idea is `MyClass` is something like a `DbContext` whose constructor takes in a `clientName` string.  Then, `getMemberNameAndValue(clientName)` contacts a fixed db (which we host) which returns the connection string to the `clientNames`'s db (we also host) as well as the "entities" that db supports.  Each entity the db support corresponds to a class member (e.g. `myObject`).  Each "Entity class member" contains `find`, `get`, `where` delegate methods for carrying out these queries for _that_ entity type and _that_ database type.  The entity's delegates are bound after the db type is found.

Answer (score 2):

Based off of the MSDN entry for `FieldInfo.SetValue` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6z33zd7h(v=vs.110).aspx)):

Get the appropriate `FieldInfo` object:

```
 FieldInfo myFieldInfo = myType.GetField(name, 
            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

Set the value:

```
myFieldInfo.SetValue(this, new SomeObject());
```

As with all reflection, its not very efficient; and there are lots of places where you could assign an incorrect type, etc. so be careful when doing this. Without seeing more code, it is unlikely that you *actually* want to use reflection here.

Comment: I was confused what "this" was referring too, until I realized it was an instance of MyClass in his example.  Code worked for me, description came up in search.

Answer (score 0):

```
FieldInfo fi = this.GetType().GetField(name, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance); //reference

this.GetType().InvokeMember(name, BindingFlags.SetField | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance, null, this, new object[]{value}); //plain setting

object value = this.GetType().InvokeMember(name, BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance, null, this, null); //plain getting
```